# Brick-walling on JS form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

Learning JS more in-depth of late, as I've not had to mess with it work. Trying to code some form validation, and it keeps "stopping" at the first input. Any advice is greatly appreciated. I have tried everything I can think of, read so many articles on form validation and nothing works. If anyone can point out my errors and "why" they're errors it'd be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
var validFirst = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;

 if (validFirst == null || validFirst == "") {
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}
else if (validFirst.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
   document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   return false;
  } 
else if (validFirst !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    return false;
  } 

var validLast = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
if (validLast == null || validLast == "") {
    document.getElementById("lastError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("last").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}
 else if (validLast.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("lastError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("last").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
  } 
else if (validLast !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("lastError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("last").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    return false;
  }
  var validEmail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
if (validEmail == null || validEmail == "") {
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}
 else if (validEmail.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
  } 
else if (validEmail !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    return false;
  }

  var validPhone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
if (validPhone == null || validPhone == "") {
    document.getElementById("phoneError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("phone").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}
 else if (validEmail.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("phoneError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("phone").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
  } 
else if (validEmail !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("phoneError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("phone").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    return false;
  }
  }

</script>
<head>
<title>Form Validation</title>
```

```
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="first" name="fname" onchange="validFirst()"></td>
            <td><span id="firstError"></span></td>
        </tr>

            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="last" name="lname" onchange="validLast()"></td>
              <td><span id="lastError"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" onchange="validEmail()"></td>
            <td><span id="emailError"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onchange="validPhone()"></td>
            <td><span id="phoneError"></span></td>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're missing a `<tr>`, a `</tr>` and a `</form>` in your HTML. Make sure that's not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the last `else` statement in each section, you're returning the form field to its "non-error" state and then returning `false`, causing the validation function to exit.

The solution is to remove this last `return false;` in each group of `if/else if` blocks:

```
 if (validFirst == null || validFirst == "") {
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}
else if (validFirst.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
  } 
else if (validFirst !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "white";
//  return false; /**** this is causing your validation function to terminate ****/
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/75rcwv8k/

Comment: Taking them out/changing the last one to "return true" doesn't make it work either.

Comment: You'll have to clarify the problem for me, then. [It seems to work fine in this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/75rcwv8k/)

Comment: The first item works, but then the rest do not, when they should all behave identically. The fiddle you provided does the same thing; only works for the first name element.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! thanks for the help, everyone!

```
function validateForm() {

var validFirst = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;

 if (validFirst == null || validFirst == "") {
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
else if (validFirst.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
   document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "red";

  } 
else if (validFirst !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("firstError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("first").style.backgroundColor = "white";

  } 

var validLast = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
if (validLast == null || validLast == "") {
    document.getElementById("lastError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("last").style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
 else if (validLast.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("lastError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("last").style.backgroundColor = "red";

  } 
else if (validLast !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("lastError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("last").style.backgroundColor = "white";

  }
  var validEmail = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
if (validEmail == null || validEmail == "") {
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
 else if (validEmail.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "red";

  } 
else if (validEmail !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "white";

  }

  var validPhone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
if (validPhone == null || validPhone == "") {
    document.getElementById("phoneError").innerHTML = "Required Field";
    document.getElementById("phone").style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
 else if (validEmail.length < 2) {         
    document.getElementById("phoneError").innerHTML = "Response too short";
    document.getElementById("phone").style.backgroundColor = "red";

  } 
else if (validEmail !== null) {         
    document.getElementById("phoneError").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("phone").style.backgroundColor = "white";

  }
  return false;
  }

</script>
<head>
<title>Form Validation</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="first" name="fname" onchange="validFirst()"></td>
            <td><span id="firstError"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="last" name="lname" onchange="validLast()"></td>
              <td><span id="lastError"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" onchange="validEmail()"></td>
            <td><span id="emailError"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onchange="validPhone()"></td>
            <td><span id="phoneError"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```